# Use Bloomberg real time data feed with xbbg

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to migrate all the bbg real time functions to Python and came across xbbg blp.live function. Not sure if anyone did something similar, but my question is whether blp.live is real real live. And looks like it will automatically connect to Bloomberg, but not sure in what situation it will lose connection (xbbg did not ask me for any login info or authentication).

Here is a sample code I tested out:

```
from xbbg import blp
import asyncio

async for d in blp.live('QQQ US Equity', flds = ['LAST_PRICE'], info=['LAST_PRICE'], max_cnt = 1):
    print(d)
```

Thank you!

Comment: It connects to your local Bloomberg session - as long as you are logged onto the terminal you will be fine. If you connect to Bloomberg Anywhere on your mobile (for example), the connection will drop.